# Find the least possible n for the power

Tags: exponentiation, number-comparison

While comparing the $123^{124}$ and $124^{123}$ (just for fun) I come up with an interesting question.

Is it possible to find the least possible natural $n$, such that $a = b - k, k > 0 \quad and \quad a^n > b^{n-1}$ ? $a$ , $b$ and $k$ are fixed.

I have no idea how to approach the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure this is clear. since you say $a=b+k$ are you trying to solve $a^n>a^{n-1}$?  Or did you intend something else? Regardless, I expect that taking logs of both sides will get you what you want.

Comment: This is not your question but a related result for comparing powers. If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x>e$ and $y>e$ and $x>y$, Then $$y^x > x^y$$ This result implies that $$123^{124}>124^{123}$$

Comment: @lulu, I am sorry for the confusion. I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov I find the question still confusing. Is $k$ fixed ? Are $a,b$ arbitary with difference $k$ ?

Comment: @Peter, I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, I am grateful for the notice you made. But I believe my question is more broad. Thank you.

Comment: The variable $k$ is extraneous here. You are looking for the minimum value $n$ for which $a^n>b^{n-1}$ for some fixed $a,b$ with $a<b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lulu suggested, take the logarithms and use the logarithm law $$\log(a^n)=n\cdot \log(a)$$ You get an inequality that you can easily solve for $n$.